# didFinishLaunchingwithOptions is calling after awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, appdelegate

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH4-SW1) says:

> Before the initial view controller is displayed, your app delegate is
>   called to give you a chance to configure the view controller.

But that is not actually happening.

1. I created project in Xcode with `single view template`.
2. In `ViewController.m` I added `awakeFromNib` method and inside I just `NSLog(@"VC")`.
3. Then in `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingwithOptions` I just `NSLog(@"AD")`
4. When I am running the project `ViewController` execute first then `AppDelegate`.
5. With out storyboard `didFinishLaunchingwithOptions` method always execute first and I was able to configure database and other initial stuff that all ViewControllers can use but now I am not able to do that.
6. `ViewController.m` is executing first and my database setup is in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Nothing is going wrong. `awakeFromNib` is called when the storyboard is **loaded**. The documentation states "before the initial view controller is **displayed**". As with your previous, now deleted question, to get an actual answer you will have to say what it is you are actually trying to do, and why this is causing you a problem. You are probably doing things in awakeFromNib that are not appropriate, but nobody knows without more information.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to do things in awakeFromNib that you should be doing in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @jrturton In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I want to create/setup/copy from main bundle database and in awakeFromNib I want to query and use the data in ViewController.m but ViewController is getting called earlier.

Comment: AwakeFromNib is the wrong place to do that. Either tell your view controller things are ready from the app delegate, or do your stuff in viewWillAppear / viewDidLoad.

Comment: @jrturton but with out storyboard didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is the first method that execute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is going wrong. awakeFromNib is called when the storyboard is **loaded**. The documentation states "before the initial view controller is **displayed**".

You are probably doing things in awakeFromNib that are not appropriate, but nobody knows without more information

The app lifecycle with storyboards is slightly different to using nibs. With nibs, you'd create and populate the initial view controller in `didFinishLaunching`. With storyboards, that's done for you, before `didFinishLaunching` is called. You can then access `self.window.rootViewController` in that method to get hold of your initial view controller.

The point remains that `awakeFromNib` is *not* a good place to be doing anything like responding to databases being set up or querying values. Your view hasn't been loaded yet. You should be doing these things later in the lifecycle.